# Frobenius-Schur indicator: why doesn't the Weyl unitary inner product qualify?

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, bilinear-form

As best as I understand, the [Frobenius Schur indicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius%E2%80%93Schur_indicator) tells us for a finite group $G$ and an irreducible representation $\rho: G \rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(V)$ (where $V$ is a vector is a vector space over the complex numbers):

> what $G$ invariant bilinear forms does $V$ possess?

I am extremely confused; Why doesn't the standard inner product:

$$
\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle: V \otimes V \rightarrow \mathbb R; 
\langle v, w \rangle \equiv \sum_{g \in G} [\rho(g)(v), \rho(g)(w)]
$$
for some inner product $[\cdot,\cdot]: V \otimes V \rightarrow \mathbb R$ qualify?

I also know that separately, the space of $G$ invariant bilinear forms must be 1-dimensional. This is because a $G$ invariant bilinear form carries the same data as a G-invariant mapping $f: V \mapsto V^\star$. However, since in the finite dimensional case, $V \simeq V^*$, we have by Schur's lemma that $f = \lambda I$ for some $I$.

Combining the two "facts", we have that

- $[\cdot, \cdot]$ is a $G$ invariant symmetric bilinear form on $V$
- The space of $G$-invariant symmetric bilinear forms is one dimensional
- Thus, **all $G-$invariant bilinear forms are 1-dimensional and symmetric**

This is clearly absurd, since the entire point of the Frobenius Schur indicator is to tell us if the space of bilinear forms is symmetric or antisymmetric.

What am I missing?

Comment: An inner product is a map $V \otimes V \to \mathbb{C}$, but it is only $\mathbb{R}$-linear: it is $\mathbb{C}$-linear in one argument, but conjugate-linear in the other. The Frobenius-Schur indicator is concerned with bilinear forms, which are $\mathbb{C}$-linear in both variables.

Comment: For a simple example, take the representation of the group of order three on $\mathbb{C}$ via a primitive root of unity $\omega$. For this to be $G$-invariant, we would need $(\omega, \omega) = (1, 1)$, but $(\omega, \omega) = \omega^2 (1, 1)$ by $\mathbb{C}$-bilinearity. So there are no nonzero $\mathbb{C}$-bilinear forms on this representation. On the other hand, if we take a sesquilinear form that second condition is $\langle \omega, \omega \rangle = \overline{\omega} \omega \langle 1, 1 \rangle = \langle 1, 1 \rangle$: there is no obstacle for $G$-invariant inner products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said yourself the indicator applies to *complex* vector spaces, then proceed to talk about invariant inner products on *real* vector spaces. See what the issue is?

For complex inner product spaces, the inner product is sesquilinear, not symmetric bilinear.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, an inner product is such that $\langle v, \lambda w \rangle = \lambda* \langle v, w \rangle$ while what we want is $\langle v, \lambda w \rangle = \lambda \langle v, w \rangle$? If so, does $\langle v, w \rangle \equiv \sum_i v_i w_i$ satisfy the criteria?

Comment: The dot product $\sum v_iw_i$ is not an inner product on $\Bbb C^n$, rather $\sum v_i\overline{w_i}$ is. And if by $\lambda\ast\langle v,w\rangle$ you mean $\overline{\lambda}\langle v,w\rangle$, then yes. (Although be careful: mathematicians may want $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ to be conjugate-linear in the second argument, while physicists may want $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ to be conjugate-linear in the first argument.)